# Migrating JIRA issues to GitLab?

Tags: jira, gitlab

Is there a way to migrate JIRA issues to GitLab EE starter?

We have two projects each having 1 board on JIRA that I would like to migrate.

Comment: This would do: https://gist.github.com/toudi/67d775066334dc024c24

Comment: That'll do.  I was wondering also if Gitlab had their own migration tool.

Comment: This is still an open issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23929

Comment: This is an updated version of referred project in my first comment. It doesn't need tokens. Fine it here: https://gist.github.com/florisb/1266d3584dbfdbd2a8a55d31e2518edd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After emailing the GitLab team, this feature is in the Roadmap and is "scheduled for release in 3-6 months" as of June 15, 2017.

And 3 to 6 months later indeed, in April 2020, for GitLab 12.10:
<sup>(I mean, talk about "[six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/6309)"!)</sup>

> ### [Import Issues from Jira to GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/04/22/gitlab-12-10-released/#import-issues-from-jira-to-gitlab)
>
> Until now, the only way to get Jira issues into GitLab was manually, with our CSV importer, or by hand-rolling your own migration utility.
>
> GitLab 12.10 includes an MVC to automatically import your Jira issues into GitLab. This is the first of many planned enhancements to make transitioning from Jira to GitLab as frictionless as possible.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/12_10/jira-importer.png]
>
> To get started, set up the Jira integration on your GitLab project, click the import icon at the top of your project’s Issue List, and select Import From Jira.

See [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/jira.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2766).

[image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/img/jira/import_issues_from_jira_button_v12_10.png]

---

Note that, with [GitLab 13.2 (July 2020)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/07/22/gitlab-13-2-released/#map-jira-users-to-gitlab-users-when-importing-issues), you now have:

> ### Map Jira users to GitLab users when importing issues

> When importing issues from Jira to GitLab, you can now map Jira users to GitLab project members prior to running the import.
> This enables the importer to set the correct reporter and assignee on the issues you’re moving to GitLab.

[image: Map Jira users to GitLab users when importing issues https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_2/user-mapping.png]

See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/jira.html#import-your-jira-project-issues-to-gitlab) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/216145).

Answer (score 0):

After emailing the GitLab team, this feature is in the Roadmap and is "scheduled for release in 3-6 months" as of June 15, 2017.

In the meantime, you can use [the script](http://gist.github.com/florisb/1266d3584dbfdbd2a8a55d31e2518edd) that @M. Awais mentioned in the comments.

Comment: after reading and forgotten issues about that sod i assumed that is even not an aswer, does script help you ? i think you even not test it